# Makefile for a single target with multiple .c and .h dependencies

Tags: c, makefile

I have this `hello-world.c` that I'd like to compile to `hello-world` binary. But `hello-world.c` depends on a few functions defined in `../helpers/a.c` and `../helpers/b.c`, and each of those helpers include `../helpers/a.h` and `../helpers/b.h` respectively.

My current Makefile looks like

```
CC      =   @gcc
CFLAGS  =   -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror
CFLAGS  +=  

LDLIBS  =   
LDLIBS  +=  

OBJS    =   ../helpers/a.o ../helpers/b.o

SOURCES =   hello-world.c
DESTS   =   hello-world

new: clean all

clean:
    @rm -rf *.o */*.o $(DESTS)

all: $(OBJS) $(DESTS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

%: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

but it doesn't work, returning `` make: *** No rule to make target `../helpers/a.o', needed by `all'.  Stop. ``

I understand that Makefile doesn't seem to see the rule for `%.o`, but I don't see why.

Edit: Makefile debug:

```
alexandernst@stupidbox:/media/sf_procmon/procmon$ make --debug=b
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Reading makefiles...
Updating goal targets....
 File `new' does not exist.
   File `clean' does not exist.
  Must remake target `clean'.
  Successfully remade target file `clean'.
   File `all' does not exist.
     File `../helpers/a.o' does not exist.
    Must remake target `../helpers/a.o'.
make: *** No rule to make target `../helpers/a.o', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

Comment: Using pattern rules on files in other folders works for me. I ran this makefile and a.o and b.o were created as expected. Are you sure you are running `make all` in the right directory?

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. I'm running make inthe right dir but I'm getting that error.

Comment: Why not put your helper functions into a library? Then you won't have to compile them each time at all.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths not enough code for a library. There are just a few functions that I use to help myself when coding.

Comment: Try removing the "@" signs from your makefile so you can see exactly what's being run. If that doesn't solve it, try "make -d" to show what is being built and what rules are being tried.

Comment: @GavinSmith Removing the ```@``` doesn't help as make doesn't even get to the compile part. It exits after printing the error. make -d outputs a *huge* amount of data (it doesn't even fit on my konsole's buffer). Any particular palce to look at?

Comment: @alexandernst: Nothing wrong with making a library with just a few functions in it, and you'll probably find you writing more general purpose functions to put it in as you progress. You may find `make --debug=b` more manageable and useful than `make -d`.

Comment: Run `make -d | less` and search for "../helpers/a.o".

Comment: Ok, this is getting weirder. Why is make trying to file ```all``` file instead of parsing it as a rule?

Comment: I don't think that's important - it's calling any target a file.

Comment: @alexandernst: It's not, look at what it's doing for `clean` first. It doesn't find a file, so it moves onto the target of the same name, it's just not actually getting to make `all` since the problem is coming while it's resolving the dependencies for that target.

Comment: Have you tried using `VPATH`? (https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#General-Search)

Comment: @Nirk Same result: http://pastebin.com/VmK9SwCq

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. When you try `make ../helpers/a.o`, does it fail? What if you remove the `%.o` rule?

Comment: Turns out a wrong clean rule had wiped some files and that's why make was acting strange.

Comment: Could you post what files were wiped in an answer for future reference?

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier to get working if you put the Makefile in the parent directory.  Then you can write something like this:

```
CC        = gcc
CFLAGS    = -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror
CPPFLAGS  = -Ihelpers

DESTS       = hello-world/hello-world
OBJS        = helpers/a.o helpers/b.o hello-world/hello-world.o

# Do not make 'all' depend directly on object files.
all: $(DESTS)

# Clean rules should always be prefixed with '-' to avoid
# errors when files do not exist.  Do not use 'rm -r' when
# there shouldn't be directories to delete; do not delete
# wildcards when you can use explicit lists instead.
# Never use '@'.
clean:
        -rm -f $(OBJS) $(DESTS)

# An explicit linkage rule is needed for each entry in DESTS.
hello-world/hello-world: hello-world/hello-world.o \
                         helpers/a.o helpers/b.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

# The main function of these dependency lists is to prevent
# Make from deleting object files after each build.  We also
# take the opportunity to specify header dependencies.
# We rely on the built-in %.o:%.c rule for commands.
hello-world/hello-world.o: hello-world/hello-world.c \
                           helpers/a.h helpers/b.h
helpers/a.o: helpers/a.c helpers/a.h
helpers/b.o: helpers/b.c helpers/b.h

# This tells Make that 'all' and 'clean' are not files to be created.
.PHONY: all clean
```

For further exposition of this technique, see the watershed paper '[Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/)' and the associated implementation notes.

Comment: I can't put it in the parent dir because the dir structure represents a few different projects without any relation (except that they share the helpers folder).

Comment: 1) It doesn't matter that the directory structure represents a few different projects whose only connection is the helpers folder; they should *still* all share the same makefile in the parent directory.  You will find that this is less trouble overall than any other form of organization.  2) `CPPFLAGS` stands for C *preprocessor* flags.  The flag variable particular to C++ is `CXXFLAGS`.  The built-in rule for compiling `.c` files uses `CFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS`; the rule for `.cc`/`.cpp` files uses `CXXFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS`.

Comment: BTW, the "implementation notes" at the link in my answer show a technique for keeping per-directory information in per-directory Makefiles while still getting the benefits of nonrecursive make.  It's much more complicated than the above, though, I wouldn't bother for small projects.

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head.  You still have some oddities (why set `CFLAGS` and then immediately add nothing to it? Why have `LDLIBS at all?  Why is `new` rather than `all` the topmost target?  `clean` is still doing unsafe and/or inadvisable things...) but none of them seems like it would cause the exact problem you are having.

Comment: CFLAGS and LDLIBS are just rests, I can delete them. new is on top because I want "make" to "make clean && make all"

Comment: That is a bad thing to want; everyone *expects* `make` to do what you have `make all` do, so you're leaving traps for your fellow programmers.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my Makefile:

```
CC      =   gcc
CFLAGS  =   -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror
CFLAGS  +=  

LDLIBS  =   
LDLIBS  +=  

OBJS    =   ../helpers/a.o ../helpers/b.o hello-world.o

SOURCES =   hello-world.c
DESTS   =   hello-world

new: clean all

clean:
    @rm -rf *.o */*.o ../helpers/*.o $(DESTS)

all: $(DESTS)

hello-world: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
```

One of the problems was that a bad clean rule that I wrote had wiped a.c and b.c and Makefile was acting because of this.